# How to check Firebase Remote Config Timeout on unity?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-remote-config

Hello so I want to check this java function on the unity

```java
FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
        .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(MINIMUM_FETCH_INTERVAL)
        .setFetchTimeoutInSeconds(FETCH_TIME_OUT)
        .build();
```

but seem there is no `config setting interval` on the unity also don't understand what said on the firebase document

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/struct/firebase/remote-config/config-settings#struct_firebase_1_1_remote_config_1_1_config_settings_1a35df0caae275b6e9a435103683cad318

here my firebse script on the unity

```cs
public static _FirebaseRemoteConfig instance;
​
    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            instance = this;
        }
        InitializeFirebase();
    }
​
    public int countingUpdate;
    public int maxCount;
​
    Firebase.DependencyStatus dependencyStatus = Firebase.DependencyStatus.UnavailableOther;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
​
    }
​
    public void InitializeFirebase()
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object> defaults =
            new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();
        defaults.Add("config_test_string", "default local string");
        defaults.Add("config_test_int", 1);
        defaults.Add("config_test_float", 1.0);
        defaults.Add("config_test_bool", false);
​
        Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.SetDefaults(defaults);
        Debug.Log("Remote config ready!");
​
        FetchFireBase();
    }
    public void FetchFireBase()
    {
        FetchDataAsync();
    }
    public void ShowData()
    {
        Debug.Log("maxCountToShowAdmob: " +
            Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.GetValue("MaxCountShowIntersitialAds").StringValue);
    }
​
    // Start a fetch request.
    public Task FetchDataAsync()
    {
        Debug.Log("Fetching data...");
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task fetchTask = Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.FetchAsync(
            TimeSpan.Zero);
        return fetchTask.ContinueWith(FetchComplete);
    }
​
    void FetchComplete(Task fetchTask)
    {
        if (fetchTask.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.Log("Fetch canceled.");
        }
        else if (fetchTask.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.Log("Fetch encountered an error.");
        }
        else if (fetchTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            Debug.Log("Fetch completed successfully!");
        }
​
        var info = Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.Info;
        switch (info.LastFetchStatus)
        {
            case Firebase.RemoteConfig.LastFetchStatus.Success:
                Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.ActivateFetched();
                Debug.Log(String.Format("Remote data loaded and ready (last fetch time {0}).",
                    info.FetchTime));
                break;
            case Firebase.RemoteConfig.LastFetchStatus.Failure:
                switch (info.LastFetchFailureReason)
                {
                    case Firebase.RemoteConfig.FetchFailureReason.Error:
                        Debug.Log("Fetch failed for unknown reason");
                        break;
                    case Firebase.RemoteConfig.FetchFailureReason.Throttled:
                        Debug.Log("Fetch throttled until " + info.ThrottledEndTime);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case Firebase.RemoteConfig.LastFetchStatus.Pending:
                Debug.Log("Latest Fetch call still pending.");
                break;
        }
    }
​
    public void DisplayAds()
    {
        countingUpdate++;
​
        if (countingUpdate % int.Parse(Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.GetValue("MaxCountShowIntersitialAds").StringValue) == 0)
        {
            //ADs ready to show
            _AdmobAds.instance.ShowInterstitialAd();
            countingUpdate = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried something like e.g. `Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.FetchTimeoutInMilliseconds = XYZ;` ? or maybe [`Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.DefaultTimeoutInMilliseconds = XYZ;`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/remote-config/firebase-remote-config#class_firebase_1_1_remote_config_1_1_firebase_remote_config_1ae6061b14c79984b71b1c143333ea3445) ?

Comment: yup then `CS0117- FirebaseRemoteConfig does not contain a definition for FetchTimeoutInMilliseconds` @derHugo

Comment: I don't have the project and this library in front of me ... simply type `Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.` and let your IDE show you which properties/fields exist there ;)

Comment: actually, FetchAsync() that similar to this also I already implement that, but I'm not sure, so this makes me confused because not like a document for `FetchIntervalSecond` exists. @derHugo

Answer (score 2):

The [7.1.0 Unity SDK](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity#version_710_-_february_16_2021) came with some changes to how Remote Config works, so the documentation can be a little confusing right now.

With the 7.1.0 SDK, the following code should work:

```
var configSettings = new Firebase.RemoteConfig.ConfigSettings()
{
  MinimumFetchInternalInMilliseconds = 42
};

FirebaseRemoteConfig.DefaultInstance.SetConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
{
  if (task.IsCompleted && task.Exception != null)
  {
    // do remote config stuff
  }
});
```

But if you're going to use `FetchAsync(TimeSpan.Zero)`, I don't think you'll find that changing the default minimum fetch interval will do anything.

I'll also warn that it looks like you're safe (just doing `Debug.Log`), but if you want to do anything with Unity objects (generally use the `UnityEngine` namespace), you probably want to change:

```
return fetchTask.ContinueWith(FetchComplete);
```

to

```
return fetchTask.ContinueWithOnMainThread(FetchComplete);
```

Comment: Hey, I am currently implementing this and noticed that `MinimumFetchInternalInMilliseconds` is actually in seconds and not milliseconds. If I set the value to `60000` (which should be 60 seconds), it does not work. If I set the value to `60`, the values expire after 60 seconds. Can you confirm this?

Comment: I'd recommend filing a bug here, since that sounds like a fairly bad issue: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues